# Expandable UICollectionView cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Is there any way to create an expandable cell in `UICollectionView`?
Here's how it looks like in the `UITableView`:

[image]

Also, the expandable `UICollectionViewCell` should have a different height(based on the number of rows in a text.)

Comment: "You know nothing John Snow" (sorry I had to :D ).

Comment: OnTopic: Are you using auto-layout? Creating Views in InterfaceBuilder or in code?

Comment: Hey, I'm setting up the collectionView in code. I use UICollectionViewLayout to change the height of a cell.

Answer (score 1):

To create an expandable and collapsible Views using table view header and by creating different sections you can follow these two tutorials. I have also created the same with the help of these tutorials.
https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-collapsible-sections-96badf3387d0

https://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/